# RegionMember[ ] in polygon

Tags: bugs, regions, computational-geometry, polygons

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 12.0.**

---

I am seeing a difference in `RegionMember[ ]` testing a point inside a 3-vertex polygon and testing a point inside a more complex polygon:

```
poly1 = {{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {2, 2}};    
Print[RegionMember[Polygon[poly1], {0, 0}]]; 
(*=>True*)   
poly2 = {{11, 10}, {10, 11}, {9, 12}, {9, 13}, {8, 14}, {7, 15}, {7, 
    16}, {6, 17}, {6, 18}, {5, 18}, {4, 18}, {3, 19}, {2, 18}, {1, 
    19}, {-1, 19}, {-2, 19}, {-3, 19}, {-4, 19}, {-5, 18}, {-4, 
    18}, {-3, 16}, {-3, 16}, {-2, 14}, {-1, 14}, {-1, 12}, {0, 
    12}, {0, 10}, {1, 10}, {2, 10}, {3, 10}, {4, 10}, {5, 9}, {7, 
    10}, {7, 9}, {9, 9}, {10, 9}}; 
Print[RegionMember[Polygon[poly2], {0, 0}]]; 
(*=>Long Expression*)
```

---

[image]

---

How can I force `RegionMember[ ]` to evaluate to `True` or `False`?

(I'm using Version 11.3.0.0 under MacOS X.)

Comment: Incidentally, I used `RegionMember[]` to help make an animation in response to the MO question, "[Visual proof of convergence for Steiner's symmetrization](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307582/6094)."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's worth reporting this to support. As a workaround you can numericize the polygon:

```
RegionMember[
    Polygon[
        N@{
            {11,10},{10,11},{9,12},{9,13},{8,14},{7,15},{7,16},
            {6,17},{6,18},{5,18},{4,18},{3,19},{2,18},{1,19},
            {-1,19},{-2,19},{-3,19},{-4,19},{-5,18},{-4,18},
            {-3,16},{-3,16},{-2,14},{-1,14},{-1,12},{0,12},
            {0,10},{1,10},{2,10},{3,10},{4,10},{5,9},{7,10},
            {7,9},{9,9},{10,9}
        }
    ],
    {0,0}
]
```

> False

Answer (score 11):

This seems like a bug. It might even be a bug I have reported in the past.

In particular, your polygon is slightly degenerate: it has `{-3, 16}` twice in a row, creating a zero-length edge. (This doesn't seem to be a sufficient condition alone to make `RegionMember` fail.)

You can remove such edges by the following replacement rule:

```
RegionMember[
 Polygon[poly2 //. {{a___, p : {x_, y_}, {x_, y_}, b___} :> {a, p, b},
                    {p : {x_, y_}, a___, {x_, y_}} :> {a, p}}], {0, 0}]
```

> False

This rule doesn't work for complicated coordinate values which have the same value but a different form (testing equality is untrivial), but it's fine with integers and rationals.

Unfortunately this is not the only kind of degeneracy which can make `RegionMember` fail. Another sort can be seen on polygons where consecutive edges overlap on the same line (this problem persists in v12.0):

```
RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], {0, 0}]
```

> RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], {0, 0}]

Numericizing the coordinates does help even in this case, though.

Answer (score 4):

In version 10.1 it seems I need to remove duplicates *and* make sure the array is unpacked:

```
RegionMember[Polygon @ Developer`FromPackedArray @ DeleteDuplicates @ poly2, {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Just noting, `DeleteDuplicates` would actually change the shape of the polygon if duplicates are not consecutive.

Comment: @kirma Good point! I guess I was only interested in making the example "work" without thought to preserving the actual intent.  It also induced packing which is how I discovered that too was a problem.